# Reorder DOM before page is loaded on tablet or desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm looking for the best way to do this. My layout is mobile first but in tablet or desktop will change for another distribution. The problem is when you access to the page for the first time from tablet or desktop since you can appreciate by a milisecond the mobile DOM version. My question is, what the best way to load the reordered DOM before loading page? Taking the javascript to the `body`? Making a loader while the DOM is being set?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Here´s my code:

```
function listenReorder( e ) {
    if ($(window).width() > 620) {
        $(".container-logo").insertAfter(".container-presentation");
        $(".languages").insertAfter(".container-presentation");
    }else{
        $(".container-presentation").insertAfter(".container-logo");
        $(".languages").insertAfter(".container-logo");
    }
};

$(window).on("load resize", listenReorder);
```

Comment: Have you tried `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: you can't reorder the DOM (using client side code) until the DOM exists. So there is no way to `reorder DOM before loading page`. Using `ready` though means you don't have to wait for all images. You could also use a loading mask until the reorder is done

Comment: @Danko Yes, perhaps that's the reason why the tablet or desktop version don't show at the moment. jQuery is waiting for the document is ready to run the function.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, maybe using a loading mask could be the solution.

Comment: media queries or writing a class to body tag using script (combined with new rules) are other possible ways

Answer (score 1):

Instead of attempting to change the layout with javascript you could use media queries + CSS flexboxes which support ordering via the [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property.

And in case you really want to do this with javascript: By the time the domcontentloaded event fires the page may already be partially rendered. Using mutation observers or request animation frame event listeners to check if the elements you want to change have already been inserted into the DOM by the HTML parser would allow you do those changes sooner, possibly before the old state becomes visible to the user.